# A continuous, path-independent, non-conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to define a non-conservative vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose line integrals don't depend on its paths. I think it could be
$$ F(x,y) = \begin{cases} (x+y, x-y) && \mbox{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$} \\ 
(2,2) &&\mbox{if $(x,y) = (0,0).$}\end{cases} $$
Is it right? Now, what about a continuous vector field with this property (non-conservative and path-independent)? Can you give me an example of it?

Comment: conservative and path-independent are equivalent on $\Bbb{R}^2$, so you can't prove such a thing.

Comment: I think this equivalence holds for continuous vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$... not in general.

Comment: Note that I asked two questions. The first one is about vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (not necessarily continuous). The second one is about continuous vector fields (not necessarily on all $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Answer (score 0):

I think the function $f(x,y) = x^{4/3} + y$ has a continuous gradient vector field. Because the gradient does not have continuous first order partial derivatives (dP/dx not continuous), it may or may not be a conservative vector field.
I ask a similar question here: [Is this gradient vector field also a conservative vector field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714121/is-this-gradient-vector-field-also-a-conservative-vector-field)